# Unable to load script. make sure you're either running a metro server react native

Tags: react-native, server, android-emulator, yarn-lock.json

When I run the application on the emulator, it works well. But when I try to run it on my device in debug mode. The error appears:
**Unable to load script. make sure you're either running a metro server react native**
Note: I'm using yarn.

Comment: Are you trying to run iOS or android?

Comment: I'm trying it on android @MichaelBahl

Comment: Did you try https://reactnative.dev/docs/running-on-device

adb -s <device name> reverse tcp:8081 tcp:8081